# Is it still called a Van Allen radiation belt if it's around another planet?

Tags: planetary-science, radiation, terminology, jupiter, van-allen-belt

Earth has (at least) 2 radiation belts called the Van Allen belts. Jupiter has similar radiation belt(s). Are they still called Van Allen belts around other planets?

---

Edit: The reason I ask is [every](http://science.howstuffworks.com/dictionary/astronomy-terms/van-allen-radiation-belts-info.htm) document I [find](http://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/van-allen-probes-spot-impenetrable-barrier-in-space) on the [VA belts](http://vanallenprobes.jhuapl.edu/newscenter/glossary.php), they're [talking](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2013/28feb_thirdbelt/) about Earth [specifically](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005Natur.437..227H).

Answer (score 3):

According to the Wikipedia article on radiation belts, only Earth's radiation belts are referred to as Van Allen belts:

> The discovery of the belts is credited to James Van Allen, and as a result the Earth's [radiation] belts are known as the Van Allen belts. ... The term Van Allen belts refers specifically to the radiation belts surrounding Earth; however, similar radiation belts have been discovered around other planets.

Since Van Allen did not discover the belts around other planets, he doesn't get his name on them.

Comment: There's an interesting history of detection in Bolton et al. [27. Jupiter's Inner Radiation Belts](https://lasp.colorado.edu/home/mop/files/2015/08/jupiter_ch27-1.pdf)